# Error free JQuery/Javascript is not working in Firefox 4 or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code: http://dpaste.org/Oerz/

The page looks as it should, with the title, 5 paragraphs and buttons all appearing. Each button is supposed to make a small alteration to a specific elements styling.

Currently no action occurs when any of the buttons are clicked.

I'm only claiming the above code is error free based on finding no errors in chrome's javascript console or firebug. Then again, I'm new to all this so I don't know if I'm using them correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Neither FireBug nor the Chrome console are magical or omniscient. If the page isn't working, then obviously it's not error-free :-)

Comment: Also, jsfiddle.net is a much more functional way to play with test/trial cases like this.

Comment: As Matt Bridges noted in a comment to one of the answers, the "c" in "onclick" should probably be lowercase. Have you tried this? Edit: just tested in jsfiddle; it works.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Yes, I changed the case of all the "C"'s to "c" and it is now working. All the JQuery examples are awesome and I'll try rewriting my code to take advantage of all your suggestions.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answers that helped you, and mark the best one as "the answer" (by clicking the little checkmark under the score) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really not utilizing the potential of jQuery here... I'm not exactly sure why your code doesn't work, but instead of looking into that specifically, I'll give you some hints on how to improve it. Most likely, it will start working in the process =)

For one thing, you never need `document.getElementById()` anymore. jQuery's selectors are way more powerful, and to select a button with `id="oneButton"` you simply use `$('#oneButton')`. Most of them looks and works like css selectors, so you already know them.

Secondly, you don't have to define all your methods with names to hook them up - instead, use anonymous functions (and hook them up using jQuery's `click` or `live`):

```
$('#oneButton').click(function() {
    // Assuming you've defined .bold{font-weight:bold;} in your stylesheet
    $('.firstDiv').addClass('bold');
    // Assuming you haven't
    $('.firstDiv').css('font-weight','bold');
    // You only need one of the two above!
});
```

Thus, the first two buttons could be hooked up to do exactly the same things using only these few lines of code:

```
$('#oneButton').click(function() { 
    $('div.firstDiv').css('font-weight', 'bold'); 
});
$('#twoButton').click(function() { 
    alert('There are ' + $('p').size() + ' paragraphs.'); 
});
```

Edit: As Mark Bridges noted in a comment to another answer, changing `onClick` to `onclick` (with a lowercase `c`) solves your immediate problem. I wouldn't be satisfied with that though, since you have jQuery at your disposal.

Answer (score 3):

If your going to use jQuery then bind to click events like this

```
$('#oneButton').click(boldTheText);
```

or

```
$('#oneButton').bind("click", boldTheText);
```

**Reference**

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/bind

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted to bind the events with the `onclick` member of a DOM element, the 'c' in click should be lower case.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning to `onClick` when you add the event handlers to your buttons. Assign to `onclick` instead -- note the lowercase "C".

There are no errors in the console because it's perfectly valid to assign something to an object's `onClick` property; the browser just won't ever use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code a little bit here to better take advantage of jquery's syntax:

```
<title>jQuery Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    $('#one').click(function() {
      $('#first').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    });
  };
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstDiv">
    <p id="first">I should be bold.</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="one">Bold</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Most importantly:

1. Use of `$('#foo')` instead of `document.getElementById('foo')` returns you jQuery objects with richer interaction semantics.
2. Use of the `.click()` method on a jquery object to define a click handler.
3. Use of the `.css()` method on a jquery object to make style changes.